# Firebase updating Query on a portion of priorty ordered list swift

Tags: swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I have a collection view where users can add photos and can also change the order of the photos. When they add photos to the view, I assign the priority value based on collectionViewImageSource.count, essentially placing it as the last image. However, I noticed that after reordering some photos and then reloading app to query images node ordered by priority, this is the priority of each image I get back.

(1)
(1)
(2)
(4)
(4)
(5)
(8)
(8)
(10)
(12)
(13)
(14)

When a user moves a photo to another index path, I'll switch the priorities of the moved images in firebase using setPriority, but obviously the images that haven't been touched keep the same priority so you begin to get duplicates.

What would be the best way to go about re-arranging a node of images priority when only 2 images priorities get changed at a time?

edit:

currently I'm using a for in loop to iterate through all the images and resetting their priority using an increment counter. This at least allows me to retrieve them in proper order each time but if there is a better please let me know.

Hey Jay, I have UserImage struct,

```
struct UserImage {

let key: String
let imageURL: String
var priority: Int?

init(key: String, imageURL: String, priority: Int?) {
    self.key = key
    self.imageURL = imageURL
    self.priority = priority
}

init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    key = snapshot.key
    imageURL = snapshot.value as! String
    priority = snapshot.priority as? Int
}
```

I have a networking class that has a function to generate all current user images, I pull the images from firebase in order of priority and create an array of userImages that i return in completion block,

```
func generateUserImages(completion: [UserImage]? -> Void) {
    guard let userId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let userRef = FirebaseData.fbData.REF_USERS.child(userId)


    userRef.child(Child.Images.camelCaseString()).queryOrderedByPriority().observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.exists() {
            var userPhotoArray = [UserImage]()
            let snapChildren = snapshot.valueInExportFormat() as! NSDictionary
            for snap in snapChildren {


                guard let imageUrl = snap.value[".value"] as? String, priority = snap.value[".priority"] as? Int, key = snap.key as? String else { return }
                let userImage = UserImage(key: key, imageURL: imageUrl, priority: priority)
                userPhotoArray.append(userImage)
                }
            var sortedArray = userPhotoArray
            sortedArray.sortInPlace({ $0.priority < $1.priority })
            print(sortedArray.count)
            completion(sortedArray)

        } else {
           completion(nil)
           print("NO USER IMAGES")
        }

    })

}
```

The next code I have in didSelectItemAtIndexPath where I display an action sheet, one of the options is to make the photo selected your primary photo(top priority photo). It's kinda messy because I still plan on working with it but any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Make Primary Photo", style: .Default, handler: { alertAction in
                let newPrimaryImageIndexPath = indexPath
                let oldPrimaryImageIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
                let indexPath1 = NSIndexPath(forItem: 1, inSection: 0)
                let newPrimaryImage = self.currentUserImages[indexPath.row]
                let oldPrimaryImage = self.currentUserImages[0]
                self.currentUserImages.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
                self.currentUserImages.insert(newPrimaryImage, atIndex: 0)
                self.currentUserImages.removeAtIndex(1)
                self.currentUserImages.insert(oldPrimaryImage, atIndex: indexPath.row)
                collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(newPrimaryImageIndexPath, toIndexPath: oldPrimaryImageIndexPath)
                collectionView.moveItemAtIndexPath(indexPath1, toIndexPath: newPrimaryImageIndexPath)
                var counter = 1
                for image in self.currentUserImages {
                    self.currentUserRef.child(Child.Images.camelCaseString()).child(image.key).setPriority(counter)
                    counter += 1
                }
```

I am storing the imageURLs in firebase database and storing the images in storage. I'm using Alamofire to get the images from database. I'm storing the images using ChildByAutoId.

Comment: Are the images stored in Firebase Database or in Storage? Can you post a snippet of your data structure as text, no images? (Firebase Console->Three dots on right->Export JSON. Also, are the image indexes being stored in an Array in code or some other method?